# What is wrong in this verilog code?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm studying verilog and trying to apply the concepts in my fpga.
It supossed to work in this way : 
When Switch 1 is on, all red leds turn on.
When Switch 2 is on, all green leds turn on.
When Switch 3 is on, all leds turn on.
The problem is when I put it in my fpga switch .
Could someone tell me why?
Here's my code  :

```
module LED (

    input CLOCK_50,
    input [17:0] SW,
    output reg [17:0] LEDR,
    output reg [9:0] LEDG
);

always@(posedge(CLOCK_50))

    begin
        case(SW[0])
            0:
                LEDR = 0;
            1: 
                LEDR = ~LEDR;
        endcase

        case(SW[1])
            0:
                LEDG = 0;
            1:
                LEDG = ~LEDG;
        endcase 
        case(SW[2])
            0:
                begin
                    LEDR = 0;
                    LEDG = 0;
                end
            1:
                begin
                    LEDR = ~LEDR;
                    LEDG = ~LEDG;
                end
        endcase 

    end
endmodule
```

Comment: you have to analize all case. what happend if sw 1 and sw 2 is on? and sw1 sw2 and sw3 is on? and other case?

Comment: why  you use SW with length 18 bits if you use only 3?

Comment: I'm just making simple examples to understand the concept.

Comment: think if SW[2] is 0 and SW[0] is 1 what hapen??

Comment: see http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00000.htm

Comment: additionally, use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) instead of blocking assignments (`=`) when assigning values in edge-triggered `always` blocks.

Comment: additionally, using constructs like `LEDR = ~LEDR;` will result with blinking diodes (with frequency equals to clock frequency)

Comment: @Qiu I noticed that when I used LEDR = 262143 the intensity of red leds are stronger than the red leds using ~LEDR.
Could you explain to me why?Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno the intensity is because with `~LEDR` in each posedge clk you toggle the value. Then the led is 50% on and 50% off and you only can see low intensity because our eyes can see htis fecuency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems in the code are:

1. for this situation is best with non-blocking assign. Explication [1](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/blocking.html)[2](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/courses/verilog/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf)
2. you are reassigning `LEDR` and `LEDG` with the `case(SW[2])` statement
3. You are toggling the values of `LEDG` and `LEDR` on each `posedge(CLOCK_50)`. this is the reason why you see low intensity in leds.

tips:

1. you can use bit notation (also hex) like `LEDG = 10'b1111111111;` or `LEDG = 10'b1111_1111_11;` (hex: 10'h3AA)
2. you can use a `case` for the `SW` like:

   ```
   case(SW)
       3'b000:
           ...
       3'b001:
           ...
       3'b010:
           ...
       3'b100:
           ...
       default:
           ...
   ```